# Streaming live video from android camera to server

Tags: android, camera

I need some help on streaming live video from android camera to server. What is the best approach in acheiving this ? Is it possible to use MediaRecorder for streaming video over internet ?

Answer (score 1):

To have access to my video camera I purchased this app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.xdevelop.rmp&hl=en

It is not maybe a dedicated "streaming application", but on of the features allows to stream camera to your desktop browser, and its easy to set up.

[I am not related with the app vendor ;)]

Answer (score -1):

You could capture the frames from the camera preview using Camera.PreviewCallback and do as you please with them.

Comment: Is not there any other way ??

Comment: that's the only way to intercept the frames unless you want to record to storage and then stream a completed file. afik.

Comment: Yes its seems only way ... if you need to make it actually live .. but will do some more research and update here if have a good answer.

Comment: Would like to update my last comment although not working on this currently. It seems possible to use protocols like RTSP to stream RTP packets with MediaRecorder but not a simpler way. This will be required when you need to deliver video (with audio) as Camera.PreviewCallback will give only picture frames not audio. Correct me if I am wrong please.